# How to prove Turan's Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, approximation-theory

For any polynomial $P_{n}(x)$ with degree $n$ that all its zeros lie in$[-1,1]$, then $\|P_{n}'(x)\|>C \sqrt{n} \|P_{n}(x)\|$ where $C$ is an absolute constant.

Comment: The standard reference is [Borwein-Erdelyi](http://books.google.com/books/about/Polynomials_and_Polynomial_Inequalities.html?id=386CC7JnuuwC). I understand you may not have access to it (neither do I at the moment), but the reference seems worth mentioning.

Comment: You are right, that is mentioned on Page434 in that book, and provide some steps to prove this statement. I'm trying now.

Comment: I think you should consult the original article by Turan. It is very nice - http://goo.gl/4J92t [pdf]

Comment: good, thank you, ivan. I've scanned Turan's article, and I should say the reference book ,5PM had mentioned, shares the same idea as Turan's article. and I had gave a prove by 5PM's reference

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to be incorrect. For instance, consider $$P_2(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$$ Then $P_2'(x) = 2x - (a+b)$. Consider $x^* = \dfrac{a+b}2$. Then we have $$P_2'(x^*) = 0$$ whereas $$P_2(x^*) =  \left(\dfrac{b-a}2\right)\left(\dfrac{a-b}2\right) = - \dfrac{(a-b)^2}4$$
which clearly violates the inequality.

Comment: I think the inequality involves supremum norms of P and of its derivative.

Comment: Notation: $\|P_{n}(x)\|=max_{x\in [-1,1]}|P_{n}(x)|$, and$\|P_{n}'(x)\|=max_{x\in [-1,1]}|P_{n}'(x)|$. so the $x^{*}$ for $P_{n}'(x)$ and $P_{n}(x)$ may not the same one

Comment: @Larry In Marvis's defense, this is a really  bad notation: to write $P_n(x)$ when you mean $P_n$ is to invite misinterpretation.